# How do I get the list of all stored procedures and their parameters starting with a certain prefix?

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000

Is there a way to query the database and retrieve a list of all stored procedures and their parameters?
I am using SQL Server 2000.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

To get information on the stored procedures:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES
```

To find the sprocs starting with a certain prefix (e.g. "usp"):

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.ROUTINES WHERE ROUTINE_NAME LIKE 'usp%'
```

To find all the parameters for a stored procedure:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME='YourSprocName'
```

To find all the parameters for all stored procedures starting with a certain prefix:

```
SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.PARAMETERS WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME LIKE 'usp%'
```

Comment: Should I change the WHERE SPECIFIC_NAME = ... to LIKE "MyTable_*"?

Comment: Updated my answer with 2 further examples, to search by a certain prefix.

Answer (score 5):

try this one :

```
select o.name,p.name from sys.all_parameters p inner join sys.all_objects o on p.object_id = o.object_id 
where o.type = 'P'
```

Answer (score 1):

To show a list of all procedures and their parameters, it would be in this way:

```
SELECT o.name AS [Procedure name], p.name as [Parameter name] 
FROM sys.parameters p INNER JOIN sysobjects o ON p.object_id = o.id
WHERE o.name LIKE 'prefix%' AND o.xtype = 'P'
```

It works in SQL Server 2016 but I guess it works in older versions too.

Answer (score -1):

the following query returns the procedures, functions and filters by a prefix.
I am not sure though, if it would work on sql server 2000. 
I leave it here the reference anyway, because it is a good useful query.

```
SELECT SCHEMA_NAME(SCHEMA_ID) AS [Schema], 
SO.name AS [ObjectName],
SO.Type_Desc AS [ObjectType (UDF/SP)],
COALESCE(P.parameter_id,0) AS [ParameterID],
COALESCE(P.name, 'NO PARAMETER')  AS [ParameterName],
COALESCE(TYPE_NAME(P.user_type_id),'')  AS [ParameterDataType],
COALESCE(P.max_length,0) AS [ParameterMaxBytes],
COALESCE(P.is_output,0) AS [IsOutPutParameter]
FROM sys.objects AS SO
LEFT OUTER JOIN sys.parameters AS P 
ON SO.OBJECT_ID = P.OBJECT_ID
WHERE SO.OBJECT_ID IN ( SELECT OBJECT_ID 
FROM sys.objects
WHERE TYPE IN ('P','FN'))
AND SO.NAME LIKE 'U%'   --starting with a certain prefix 
ORDER BY [Schema], SO.name, P.parameter_id
GO
```